# Dynamic radiobutton set an added listitem as selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

Hi I have a dynamic radiobutton

aspx-file

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="MoneyTransfer" runat="server" CssClass="darkgrey">
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

aspx.cs-file

```
MoneyTransfer.Items.Add(new ListItem("BankTransfer","BankTransfer", true));
MoneyTransfer.Items.Add(new ListItem("PayPal","PayPal", true));
```

What do I have to do to get the first listItem to be the selected one ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set Selected Property of listItem to true.

```
ListItem ls =new ListItem("BankTransfer", "BankTransfer" ,true);
            ls.Selected=true;
            ListItem ls2 = new ListItem("PayPal", "PayPal", true);
            MoneyTransfer.Items.Add(ls);
            MoneyTransfer.Items.Add(ls2);
```

Comment: thk u, this way it also changes the selected listitem if i select another item

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried?

```
   MoneyTransfer.SelectedIndex = 0;
```